# Get the index of the tapped Element in CarrouselView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin, I would like to get the idex of the tapped element in my CarouselView

Here is the Xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  x:Name="currentPage">

<StackLayout >

<CarouselView x:Name="TestList"  >
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate>

        <StackLayout >


                <StackLayout Grid.Row="3"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">


                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CarouselItemTapped,Source={x:Reference currentPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                </StackLayout>


        </StackLayout>

            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is my c# code :

Initialization:

```
 public ICommand CarouselItemTapped { get; set; }  // initialize my command
 new List<TestModel> ListWordsTest = new List<TestModel>(); // initialize my list of TestModel


      // the Model I use  get strings elements declared as Public {get; set;}
       TestModel testmodel = new TestModel 
            {
                Word1 = "word1",  // type string
                Word2 = "word2",  //type string

            };
```

Get Tapped Element information

```
   //When I tapped The carousel I get information like this
   CarouselItemTapped = new Xamarin.Forms.Command((selectItem) => {

         var mynews = selectItem //as IDoNotKnow  I would like to get the item index 
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [Position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.carouselview.position?view=xamarin-forms) property will tell you the index of the visible item, and [CurrentItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.carouselview.currentitem?view=xamarin-forms) is the actual item.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `ListWordsTest` is your carousel view's items source and then we could get the index through:

```
CarouselItemTapped = new Xamarin.Forms.Command((selectItem) => 
{

    var mynews = selectItem; //as IDoNotKnow  I would like to get the item index 

    var index = ListWordsTest.IndexOf((TestModel)selectItem);
});
```